# Is it possible to replace all strings except one in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

My list is this: `[ '030', '040', '050', '060', '070', '080', '090', '100', '110' ]`

I wanted to know if it's possible to replace all zero's with nothing except the one in '100', in there i want just to replace the last one so it would be '10'.

```js
let sizeCodes = body['items'][0]['product']['possibilities']['size']
let codeList = []
sizeCodes.forEach(sizeCode => {
    sizeC = sizeCode['code']
    codeList.push(sizeC)
})
codeList.forEach(code => {
    let variants = body['items'][0]['product']['variantOptions']['variants'][`${code}`]['stockLevel']['stockLevel']
    log('Size: ' + code.replace(/0/g, '') + '    |    Stock: ' + variants, 'info')
})
```

This is what i tried but obviously that replaces all zero's. Also i don't want to do that in the actual array, the '030' stands for size 3, '040' for size 4, etc. i just want to make it look cleaner by outputing that instead.

Comment: Parse them to integers and divide by ten?

Comment: `arr.map(n => n / 10)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to strip any leading zeros and divide all the values by ten.

If so:

```js
const codes =  [ '030', '040', '050', '060', '070', '080', '090', '100', '110' ];

const adjustedCodes = codes.map(n => (n / 10).toString());

console.log(adjustedCodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Improvemement of [JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57082052/860099) answer, probably the shortest way of do it

```
codes.map(x=>''+x/10);
```

```js
let codes = [ '030', '040', '050', '060', '070', '080', '090', '100', '110' ]

let r = codes.map(x=>''+x/10);

console.log(r);
```